# Postgres indexes statistics

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.6

Does `ANALYZE` collect statistics on indexes or only on tables?

What is the right way to get the up-to-date indexes usage and statistics?

My version is Postgres 9.6

Answer (score 3):

`ANALYZE` collects statistics on the distribution of the values in table columns.

With a normal index, you don't need to collect any statistics for the index, because all you need to know is the distribution of the column values.

So it does not matter if you `ANALYZE` before or after `CREATE INDEX`.

The exception to this rule are indexes on an expression.

For these, `ANALYZE` will collect data on the distribution of the *values of the expression*, so `ANALYZE` after `CREATE INDEX` will always improve the planner's estimates if that expression is used in a query. This is true, no matter if the index ends up being used during query execution or not.

Statistics on *index usage* are a completely different thing. You find them in `pg_stat_all_indexes`.

Comment: Thanks. But for the distribution of the column values, isn't ANALYZE needed? Also - what about Statistics on index usage. How can I ensure that what I see in pg_stat_all_indexes is up to date?

Comment: Of course `ANALYZE` is needed, but that is independent of whether you create an index or not. `pg_stat_all_indexes` will always contain more or less up to data data unless you have broken statistics collection (error messages about "stale statistics" in the log, or the statistics collector isn't running, or [other problems](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/stale-statistics-cause-table-bloat/)).